# Openshift Wordpress site custom domain name 'www' doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, openshift-online-2

I use Opemshift to host my Wordpress site. I use a custom domain name for my site. I have also added an alias for www.example.com.

I use Cloudflare for DNS and I have created a CNAME record for www.example.com to wp-myapp.rhcloud.com as instructed on the Openshift docs.

While my naked domain name works, example.com, prefixing it with 'www' leads to an infinite waiting mode.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "infinite waiting mode"? Assuming that you have the DNS entry in there properly, that actually isn't an error message that CloudFlare would return.